# Test an element is in viewport with protractor

Tags: angular, testing, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I want to test if my app scrolled to a specific post inside a thread page.

Initially I thought `isDisplayed` might help, and coded something like:

```
element(by.id(postId)).isDisplayed().then((isDisplayed) => {
  expect(isDisplayed).toBe(true);
});
```

After a closer reading of the [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed), `isDisplayed` does not check if an element is inside the viewport.

A hacky way would be to calculate the positions of various elements, starting with the scrollable parent (which is not `window` in my case).

Is there a best practice for checking this?

Answer (score 3):

First idea (which you mentioned):

- create class MyRect extend DOMRect
- create function `getBoundingClientMyRect` base on `getBoundingClientRect`
- create function `getWindowMyRect` base on `(0, 0, wWidth, wHeight)`

  `let wHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  let wWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;`
- create method `isInsideMyRect` in MyRect - base on https://gist.github.com/davidtheclark/5515733
- create method `isPartOfMyRect` in MyRect - base on https://gist.github.com/davidtheclark/5515733#gistcomment-2113166

`el.getWindowMyRect().isInsideMyRect(getWindowMyRect())`

This method does **not solve the problem with internal scrolls** inside the page

---

Secand Idea:

- `elm.getBoundingClientRect()` and note the value
- scroll to element if need:
  `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();", elm.getWebElement());`
- `elm.getBoundingClientRect()` - again and compare with previous value if the value has been changed then the scrolling was necessary